# Asignar un Array a un input

Tags: javascript, laravel-blade

Tengo que editar los detalles de una guía de remisión para lo cual tengo el siguiente código que me carga los valores de la tabla detalle

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($detalles as $det)
        <tr>            
            <input type="hidden" name="id_detalle[]" value="{{ $det->id_detalle }}">
            <td><input style=" width : 60px; border: none " type="number" name="cantidad[]" id="cantidad" value="{{ $det->cantidad }}"></td>
            <td><input style=" width : 600px; border: none " type="text" readonly name="descripcion[]" id="descripcion[]" value="{{ $det->descripcion }}"></td>
            <td><input style=" width : 90px; border: none " type="number" step="0.01" name="v_unitario[]" id="v_unitario" value="{{ $det->v_unitario }}"></td>
            <td><input style=" width : 90px; border: none " type="number" readonly id="v_parcial" name="v_parcial[]" value="{{ $det->v_parcial }}"></td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
```

lo siguiente es capturar los valores de cantidad y v_unitario y en un array v_parcial lo que hago es multiplicar v_parcial=cantidad*v_unitario de la siguiente manera

```
function cantidad()
{
    //Obtengo todos los campos con el nombre cantidad[]
    var cantidad = document.getElementsByName("cantidad[]");
    var v_unitario = document.getElementsByName("v_unitario[]");
    //Creo el arreglo donde almaceno sus valores
    var cant = [];
    var unit = [];
    var parc = [];
    //Recorro todos los nodos que encontre que coinciden con ese nombre
    for(var i=0;i<cantidad.length;i++){
        //Añado el valor que contienen los campos
        cant.push(cantidad[i].value);
        unit.push(v_unitario[i].value);
        parc[i] = cant[i]*unit[i];
    }
}
```

mi pregunta es como almacenar los valores del array "parc" en el

```
<input id="v_parcial" name="v_parcial[]">
```

---

**dddenis**
se utiliza para realizar otros cálculos y también es para mostrar y si lo mostraría seria de la siguiente forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tal vez lo qué intentes con el input sería más adecuado utilizar un select multiple

Comment: no por que en ese input almaceno la multiplicacion de cantidad * v_unitario

Comment: el cálculo es sólo para mostrar? o se usa en el backend? es decir es necesario hacerlo en el front, o se puede pre o post procesar directamente en php? si es para mostrarlo, cómo querrías que se muestre?

Answer (score 0):

El valor lo seteas de la misma manera que lees los otros valores, con el array de getByName, algo asi:

```
v_parcial[i].value = cantidad[i].value * v_unitario[i].value;
```

Cómo y cuando se calcula eso lo verás, en este ejemplo le puse un evento on change a las 2 columnas que cambian el resultado.

Hay mucho lugar para optimizar, tomalo como un inicio.

```js
// defino globales
 var cantidad , v_unitario, v_parcial = [];

// helper
function addEventHandler(elem, eventType, handler) {
    if (elem.addEventListener)
        elem.addEventListener (eventType, handler, false);
    else if (elem.attachEvent)
        elem.attachEvent ('on' + eventType, handler); 
}

// on load
addEventHandler(document, 'DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    //Obtengo todos los campos con el nombre cantidad[]
    cantidad = document.getElementsByName("cantidad[]");
    v_unitario = document.getElementsByName("v_unitario[]");
    
    //console.log(cantidad , v_unitario, v_parcial);

    for(var i=0;i<cantidad.length;i++){
      addEventHandler(cantidad[i], 'change', function() {
        calculaCantidad();
      });
      addEventHandler(v_unitario[i], 'change', function() {
        calculaCantidad();
      });
    }
});
   
    
function calculaCantidad()
{
    //Obtengo todos los campos con el nombre cantidad[]
    cantidad = document.getElementsByName("cantidad[]");
    v_unitario = document.getElementsByName("v_unitario[]");
    v_parcial = document.getElementsByName("v_parcial[]");

    //Creo el arreglo donde almaceno sus valores
    var cant = [];
    var unit = [];
    var parc = [];
    //Recorro todos los nodos que encontre que coinciden con ese nombre
    for(var i=0;i<cantidad.length;i++){
        //Añado el valor que contienen los campos
        cant.push(cantidad[i].value);
        unit.push(v_unitario[i].value);
        parc[i] = cant[i]*unit[i];
        
        v_parcial[i].value = cantidad[i].value * v_unitario[i].value;
    }
}
    

calculaCantidad();
```

```css
input {
background:#fe0;
max-width:320px!important;
}
tbody {
background:#fafafa;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
    @foreach($detalles as $det)
        <tr>            
            <input type="hidden" name="id_detalle[]" value="{{ $det->id_detalle }}">
            <td><input style=" width : 60px; border: none " type="number" name="cantidad[]" id="cantidad" value="1"></td>
            <td><input style=" width : 500px; border: none " type="text" readonly name="descripcion[]" id="descripcion[]" value="{{ $det->descripcion }}"></td>
            <td><input style=" width : 90px; border: none " type="number" step="0.01" name="v_unitario[]" id="v_unitario" value="5"></td>
            <td><input style=" width : 90px; border: none " type="number" readonly id="v_parcial" name="v_parcial[]" value=""></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>            
            <input type="hidden" name="id_detalle[]" value="{{ $det->id_detalle }}">
            <td><input style=" width : 60px; border: none " type="number" name="cantidad[]" id="cantidad" value="{{ $det->cantidad }}"></td>
            <td><input style=" width : 500px; border: none " type="text" readonly name="descripcion[]" id="descripcion[]" value="{{ $det->descripcion }}"></td>
            <td><input style=" width : 90px; border: none " type="number" step="0.01" name="v_unitario[]" id="v_unitario" value="{{ $det->v_unitario }}"></td>
            <td><input style=" width : 90px; border: none " type="number" readonly id="v_parcial" name="v_parcial[]" value="{{ $det->v_parcial }}"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>            
            <input type="hidden" name="id_detalle[]" value="{{ $det->id_detalle }}">
            <td><input style=" width : 60px; border: none " type="number" name="cantidad[]" id="cantidad" value="{{ $det->cantidad }}"></td>
            <td><input style=" width : 500px; border: none " type="text" readonly name="descripcion[]" id="descripcion[]" value="{{ $det->descripcion }}"></td>
            <td><input style=" width : 90px; border: none " type="number" step="0.01" name="v_unitario[]" id="v_unitario" value="{{ $det->v_unitario }}"></td>
            <td><input style=" width : 90px; border: none " type="number" readonly id="v_parcial" name="v_parcial[]" value="{{ $det->v_parcial }}"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>            
            <input type="hidden" name="id_detalle[]" value="{{ $det->id_detalle }}">
            <td><input style=" width : 60px; border: none " type="number" name="cantidad[]" id="cantidad" value="{{ $det->cantidad }}"></td>
            <td><input style=" width : 500px; border: none " type="text" readonly name="descripcion[]" id="descripcion[]" value="{{ $det->descripcion }}"></td>
            <td><input style=" width : 90px; border: none " type="number" step="0.01" name="v_unitario[]" id="v_unitario" value="{{ $det->v_unitario }}"></td>
            <td><input style=" width : 90px; border: none " type="number" readonly id="v_parcial" name="v_parcial[]" value="{{ $det->v_parcial }}"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>            
            <input type="hidden" name="id_detalle[]" value="{{ $det->id_detalle }}">
            <td><input style=" width : 60px; border: none " type="number" name="cantidad[]" id="cantidad" value="{{ $det->cantidad }}"></td>
            <td><input style=" width : 500px; border: none " type="text" readonly name="descripcion[]" id="descripcion[]" value="{{ $det->descripcion }}"></td>
            <td><input style=" width : 90px; border: none " type="number" step="0.01" name="v_unitario[]" id="v_unitario" value="{{ $det->v_unitario }}"></td>
            <td><input style=" width : 90px; border: none " type="number" readonly id="v_parcial" name="v_parcial[]" value="{{ $det->v_parcial }}"></td>
        </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: la multiplicacion esta muy bien pero como puedo asignar al value del input

Comment: asignarlo a que?

Comment: al <input style=" width : 90px; border: none " type="number" readonly id="v_parcial" name="v_parcial[]" value="{{ $det->v_parcial }}"> ya que estamos editando el valor parcial